# Centering a css dropdown menu

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu, center, alignment

I'm trying to center my css dropdown menu, but I can't seen to get it to work! I've tried adding text-align: center and margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto, but all that gets centered are the dropdown li-items. How is this done?

Here's the css:

```
.bg {background-color: #008503;}
.menu {padding:0 0 0 32px; margin:0; list-style:none; height:30px; background-color: #1e52b8; position:relative; font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
.menu li.top {display:block; float:left; position:relative;}
.menu li a.top_link {display:block; float:left; height:30px; line-height:33px; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; padding:0 0 0 12px; cursor:pointer;}
.menu li a.top_link span {float:left; font-weight:bold; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:30px;}
.menu li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:40px; background:url(images/down.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover {color:#000; background-color: #008503;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span {background-color: #008503;}
.menu li a.top_link:hover span.down {background-color: #FF0000;}

.menu li:hover > a.top_link {color:#FFF; background-color: #008503;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span {background-color: #008503;}
.menu li:hover > a.top_link span.down {background-color: #FF0000;}

.menu table {border-collapse:collapse; width:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}

.menu a:hover {visibility:visible;}
.menu li:hover {position:relative; z-index:200;}

.menu ul, 
.menu :hover ul ul, 
.menu :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

.menu :hover ul.sub {left:0; top:30px; right:2px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0; border:1px solid #008503; white-space:nowrap; width:200px; height:auto;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li {display:block; height:20px; position:relative; float:left; width:250px;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a {font-weight:normal;display:block; font-size:11px; height:20px; width:192px; line-height:20px; text-indent:5px; color:#000; text-decoration:none; border:3px solid #fff; border-width:0 0 0 3px;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a.fly {background:#fff url(images/arrow.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a:hover {background:#1e52b8; color:#fff;}
.menu :hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover {background:#999999 url(images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat; color:#fff;}
.menu :hover ul li:hover > a.fly {background:#999999 url(images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 7px no-repeat; color:#fff;} 

.menu :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
.menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul
{left:90px; top:-4px; background: #fff; padding:3px 0; border:1px solid 999999; white-space:nowrap; width:93px; z-index:200; height:auto;}
```

And here's the html:

```
<div style="width: 980px"> <!-- container -->
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>About us</span></a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu This is some longer text</a></li>           
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>The island</span></a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu This is some longer text</a></li>           
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Hotels</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Tours</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Reservation</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Contact us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using float, the only way to center it is to apply a width to the containing element and use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto. There is no way to do this will retaining the flexible width.

An alternative to float would be display:inline-block; These can be centered using text-align:center, but you'll have to rework the css.

Comment: Thanks, works great!
I'm using the cleaner solution of display: inline-block.

Comment: Just a word of caution. If using inline block whitespace between the elements is rendered (where it is not when using float). To make the elements touch each other make sure there is no whitespace between them in your html.

Comment: anychance you could explain how you solved this, i'm no a css expert but am trying to get a multi-dropdown menu for wordpress centered...

Comment: @DizzyBryanHigh just start a new question here on SO

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way to do it, you can put a div container around the menu...

#menuContainer{margin: auto;}

<div id='menuContainer' style="width: 980px">

Comment: Actually I tried that, but as Gerben says, you can't because of the float: left.