# Centering menu in header

Tags: php, html, css

How can I center the menu/navigation in header?

PHP file looks like this

```
<div class="menu-and-contact-wrap">
    <?php
    $header_phone = get_option('theme_header_phone');
    if( !empty($header_phone) ){
        echo '<h2  class="contact-number"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.$header_phone.' <span class="outer-strip"></span></h2>';
    }
    ?>

    <!-- Start Main Menu-->
    <nav class="main-menu">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
            'menu_class' => 'clearfix'
        ));
        ?>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Main Menu -->
</div>
```

And CSS file looks like this

```
.menu-and-contact-wrap {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-menu {
    margin-top: 42px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.main-menu ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .main-menu ul li.current-menu-parent > a, .main-menu ul li.current-menu-item > a, .main-menu ul li.current_page_item > a, .main-menu ul li:hover > a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ec894d;
}
.main-menu ul li a {
    font-family:"Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #afb4b5;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 10px;
}
.main-menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ec894d;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 888;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #dc7d44;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 10px 12px;
    color: white;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li ul {
    background-color: #dc7d44;
    top: 0px;
    left: 220px;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #d0743d;
}
.main-menu .responsive-nav {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I tried to change them as you can see above in CSS, but without any success

In default they looked like this:

Menu-and-contact-wrap looked like this

```
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
```

And Main-menu looked like this before

```
 margin-top: 42px;
 float: right;
```

Thank you!

Comment: *"Since you are using float, the only way to center it is to apply a width to the containing element and use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto. There is no way to do this will retaining the flexible width.

An alternative to float would be display:inline-block; These can be centered using text-align:center, but you'll have to rework the css."* - From => http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550977/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Here are two.

1. Set a non-100% width on `.main-menu` and then add `margin: 0 auto`
2. Remove the floats from `.main-menu ul li`, add `display: inline-block` to it and add `text-align: center` to `.main-menu`